# jquery fade effects on individual elements on load

Tags: jquery, onload, onload-event

First off, I'm not a web designer, I'm just a geek trying to help out a friend.

I'm working on a graphic intensive website (it's a photography website) which causes the page to load slowly. The biggest delay is portfolio thumbnails, which are normally hidden by a jquery slider. Because the page may display incorrectly before it's finished loading (and that looks tacky), I implemented a loading graphic that disappears on `$(window).load()`. But because that waits for all of the graphics to load, that loading graphic can spin for 10 seconds or more before displaying the page (depending on bandwidth).

What I want to do is display individual elements, with pretty jquery effects, as they load. That way the viewer can start seeing content right away and it still looks pretty.

So I set some elements to `display:none` and then call a `fadeIn()` and/or a `slideDown()` function on it at the end of my page. That works, but sometimes the `fadeIn()` function runs before the graphics are fully loaded, so they still appear to pop in. But if I try to wrap the `fadeIn()` function inside `('#element').load()` it doesn't work. I can put all of the fade effects in a `window.load()`, which looks pretty, but that defeats the purpose since it still waits on all of those thumbnails.

Alternatively, if there's a way to exclude certain images from the `window.load()` event? Or to add the thumbnail galleries dynamically after `window.load()`? Right now the page is fairly static, just some pretty jquery sliders and a lightbox.

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 sourced from Google. If there's another or better way to make the page render pretty, I'm all ears.

The test site URL is [here](http://www.arrington-photography.com/index2.html) . My vision I'd like to see is to display the background and loading graphic, then `slideDown()` the logo, followed by `fadeIn()` the picture frame, remove the loading graphic, fade in the picture frame content, then fade in the bottom navigation menu while sliding down the left navigation menu.

(edit)
Here's a more detailed description of the problem I'm trying to work around. If the whole page takes 10 seconds to load:

@1 second all of my text content is displayed in block and looks like a poorly designed 8th grade class project from 1995.

@2-5 seconds `document.ready()` fires and the slider script finishes parsing the page and moves the text content container elements into place in a really jumpy and ugly fashion. Now the layout looks alright.

@10 seconds the thumbnails finally finish loading and `window.load()` fires.

My current workaround starts fading in container elements after the slider script finishes, but some of those elements may not have finished loading and so they sometimes appear to pop in instead of fading in.

Comment: +1 for `I'm not a web designer, I'm just a geek`

Answer (score 1):

What part of your question comes down to is checking for each `img` to load and then <kbd>fadeIn</kbd> the corresponding element instead of doing them all at once.

For example:

```
$("img").load(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn(1000);
}).each(function() {
   if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

You can find a working example of that implementation [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wFvC7/).

Comment: I'm a corvette man myself :P My day job is sys admin, so not a web designer, just a geek :) I assume it's the this.complete that forces the fadeIn to wait until the object is loaded?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes exactly. I hope it works combined with the jquery slider. Btw it's very weird that the page loads slow because of **thumbnails**! Here read [this](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/site-speed-performance/). Also, here in Europe we think corvette are plastic cars. We prefer [solid cars](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8ajI8txGsM). No offence though :)

Comment: After a bit of fiddling and testing, it appears your snippet doesn't work for container elements. I need to fade in container elements that may contain text and images. I added more detail to my OP. And yeah, the Corvette is plastic, but it looks dang sexy.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with essentially what I'm doing now. The fiddle loads smoothly, of course, because there's behind the scenes magic underlying the site that I wish I knew. I need to make sure those container elements `#heading` and `#photoFrame` don't fade in until they've finished loading. And also, the `delay()` function doesn't seem to like me, so I can't force the second element to wait until the first one has faded in.
http://jsfiddle.net/82rKy/5/

Comment: Coming back and seeing this 3 years later, with a little more experience, the problem was that the page was not just downloading 100+ thumbnails, but also loading the full sized images required for the lightbox. The best solution would be to implement a lazy-loader for all of the photos, so that the page would have to wait for only layout related images before $window.load() fires. A lazy-loader combined with this fadeIn solution would make for a very smoothly loading page. Of course it's moot, about a year ago the client moved on to a dedicated photography host instead of a custom site.

Comment: @Thomas That sounds like a good solution indeed! Sorry you lost the client.